# INVALID STATUS on ContentVersion create from Attachment

Tags: apex, attachment, contentversion, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink

I'm currently trying to create ContentVersion records from Attachment ones but it's giving me the following error:

**INVALID_STATUS, Documents in a user's private library must always be owned by that user.: [OwnerId]**

Code:

```
List<Attachment> attLIST = [SELECT Id, Name, Body, BodyLength, ContentType, Description, OwnerId, ParentId, IsPartnerShared FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId = :currentParentID LIMIT 1];
ContentVersion cv =  new ContentVersion(
    Title = attLIST[0].Name.substringBefore('.'),
    PathOnClient = attLIST[0].Name,
    VersionData = attLIST[0].Body,
    IsMajorVersion = true,
    OwnerId = attLIST[0].OwnerId,
    ContentLocation = 'S',
    SharingOption = attLIST[0].IsPartnerShared ? 'A' : 'R',
    FirstPublishLocationId = attLIST[0].OwnerId
);
insert cv;
List<ContentDocument> cdLIST = [SELECT Id, Title, LatestPublishedVersionId, FileType, ContentSize FROM ContentDocument ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC];
ContentDocumentLink cdl = new ContentDocumentLink(LinkedEntityId = attLIST[0].ParentId,
                                                  ContentDocumentId = cdLIST[0].Id,
                                                  ShareType = 'V');
insert cdl;
```

What am I doing wrong?